# HTML5 canvas images are not loading using drawImage()

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, game-development

I'm following a tutorial on a flappy bird game by freeCodeCamp
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pufKO5EG8nc

But I'm doing it using a class to learn more about it.

The problem is, the images do not load, while in the video they load fine.

I googled around and learned of the onload event, implemented it in there, but still no bite, and no error messages in the console.

Even without the onload events, why does the video's images load, but mine don't? >:(

**My HTML code:**

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="512">
</canvas>
```

**My JS code:**

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
class Game {
    constructor(c) {
        this.c = c; //canvas
        this.ctx = c.getContext("2d"); // context
        this.sprites = 5;
        this.loadedSprites = 0;

        this.player = new Image(); // define images
        this.bg = new Image();
        this.fg = new Image();
        this.north = new Image();
        this.south = new Image();

        this.pX = 10; // player starting location
        this.pY = 150;

        // set sprite locations and load.
        this.player.src = "images/crab.png";
        this.player.onload = this.draw;
        this.bg.src = "images/bg.png";
        this.bg.onload = this.draw;
        this.fg.src = "images/fg.png";
        this.fg.onload = this.draw;
        this.north.src = "images/obstacle.png";
        this.gap = 80;
        this.constant = this.north.height + this.gap;
        this.north.onload = this.draw;
        this.south.src = "images/obstacle.png";
        this.south.onload = this.draw;
    }

    //draw images
    draw() {
        this.loadedSprites += 1;
        if (this.loadedSprites >= this.sprites) {
            this.ctx.drawImage(this.bg, 0, 0);
            this.ctx.drawImage(this.north, 100, 0);
            this.ctx.drawImage(this.south, 0, 0 + this.constant);
            this.ctx.drawImage(this.fg, 0, this.c.height - this.fg.height);
            this.ctx.drawImage(this.player, this.pX, this.pY);
        }
    }
}
let game = new Game(canvas);
```

Comment: You said the images aren't loading for you. What specifically is happening? Are the images failing to load? Are the images loaded but now showing on the screen? Or do you have another error in the console related to loading the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has to do with the **scope** - which refers to the accessibility of variables, objects and functions - and the meaning of the **this** keyword depending on the actual scope.

To get a better understanding let's have a look at the following example:

```js
class Game {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Game constructor:", this);
    this.player = new Image();
    this.player.onload = this.draw;
    this.player.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";
  }

  draw() {
    console.log("draw:", this);
  }
}
let game = new Game();
```

If you click 'Run code snippet', you should see the following output in the console:

```
Game constructor: {}
draw: <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></img>
```

As you can see a call to **this** inside `draw()` does not refer to the same thing anymore. In the first case it's an object instance of Game (hinted by the curly brackets) and in the second case it's an instance of a HTMLImageElement.

So your code simply fails because:

```
this.loadedSprites += 1;
if (this.loadedSprites >= this.sprites) {
```

don't reference the Game class's private variables `loadedSprites` and `sprites` - in fact it doesn't refer anything at all as it's simply undefined within the scope of the draw function thus `loadedSprites` doesn't ever get incremented.

One workaround is passing the context of the Game class to each Image instance using a new property e.g. `.reference`.

```
this.player = new Image();
this.player.reference = this;
this.player.onload = this.draw;
```

and use it inside draw() like:

```
draw() {
     this.reference.loadedSprites += 1;
}
```

Here's a complete example based on your code:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
class Game {
  constructor(c) {
    this.c = c; //canvas
    this.ctx = c.getContext("2d"); // context
    this.sprites = 5;
    this.loadedSprites = 0;

    this.player = new Image(); // define images
    this.player.reference = this;
    this.bg = new Image();
    this.bg.reference = this;
    this.fg = new Image();
    this.fg.reference = this;
    this.north = new Image();
    this.north.reference = this;
    this.south = new Image();
    this.south.reference = this;

    this.pX = 10; // player starting location
    this.pY = 150;

    // set sprite locations and load.

    this.player.onload = this.draw;
    this.player.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/237/20/20";

    this.bg.onload = this.draw;
    this.bg.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/22/20/20";

    this.fg.onload = this.draw;
    this.fg.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/30/20/20";

    this.gap = 80;
    this.constant = this.north.height + this.gap;

    this.north.onload = this.draw;
    this.north.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/37/20/20";

    this.south.onload = this.draw;
    this.south.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/137/20/20";
  }

  //draw images
  draw() {
    let ref = this.reference;
    ref.loadedSprites += 1;
    if (ref.loadedSprites >= ref.sprites) {
      ref.ctx.drawImage(ref.bg, 0, 0);
      ref.ctx.drawImage(ref.north, 100, 0);
      ref.ctx.drawImage(ref.south, 0, 0 + ref.constant);
      ref.ctx.drawImage(ref.fg, 0, ref.c.height - ref.fg.height);
      ref.ctx.drawImage(ref.player, ref.pX, ref.pY);
    }
  }
}
let game = new Game(canvas);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="512">
</canvas>
```

Comment: This reference concept, I haven't seen it in anywhere yet and your solution instantly solved everything. I do wonder what other solutions can be used here ;o