# drawImage() works outside of loop, but not inside?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm making a flappy bird-like game. The problem is, the images do not load in the loop within the draw() function. If I were to put the drawImage()'s outside of the loop (like the rest of the images), then they would work.

No errors in the console, the two images inside the for loop do not appear and I just don't understand why >:/

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="512">
</canvas>
```

Here's the JS code, where I made it in a class:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
class Game {
    constructor(c) {

        this.c = c; //canvas
        this.ctx = c.getContext("2d"); // context
        this.sprites = 5;
        this.loadedSprites = 0;
        this.score = 0;
        this.gravity = 1.5

        this.player = new Image(); // define images
        this.player.reference = this;
        this.bg = new Image();
        this.bg.reference = this;
        this.fg = new Image();
        this.fg.reference = this;
        this.north = new Image();
        this.north.reference = this;
        this.south = new Image();
        this.south.reference = this;

        //obstacle coordinates
        this.obstacle = [];
        this.obstacle[0] = {
            x: this.c.width,
            y: 0,
            // reference: this
        }
        this.obstacle.reference = this;

        this.pX = 10; // player starting location
        this.pY = 150;

        // set sprite locations and load.
        this.player.onload = this.draw;
        this.player.src = "images/crab.png";

        this.bg.onload = this.draw;
        this.bg.src = "images/bg.png";

        this.fg.onload = this.draw;
        this.fg.src = "images/fg.png";

        this.north.onload = this.draw;
        this.north.src = "images/obstacle.png";

        this.gap = 85;
        this.constant = this.north.height + this.gap;

        this.south.onload = this.draw;
        this.south.src = "images/obstacle.png";


        console.log(`AAA: ${this.obstacle[0].x}`);
        console.log(`LAUNCH is: ${this.obstacle[0]}`);



        $(document).on('keydown', (e) => { this.moveUp(e.key) });
        console.log("Game constructor:", this);
    }

    loadObstacle() {
        return this.obstacle;
    }

    saveObstacle(obstacle) {
        this.obstacle = obstacle;
    }

    draw() {
        let ref = this.reference;
        ref.loadedSprites += 1;
        if (ref.loadedSprites >= ref.sprites) {
            let constant = ref.gap + ref.north.height;
            let obstacle = ref.loadObstacle(); // this is actually not needed, since ref.obstacle odes the same thing. Just thought I'd try something else
            for (var i = 0; i < obstacle.length; i++) {
                ref.ctx.drawImage(ref.north, obstacle[i].x, obstacle[i].y);
                ref.ctx.drawImage(ref.south, obstacle[i].x, obstacle[i].y + constant);
                // ref.ctx.drawImage(ref.north, 250, 0);    even adding these two from below, they do not show up
                // ref.ctx.drawImage(ref.south, 250, 0 + constant);
                obstacle[i].x--;

                if (obstacle[i].x == 125) {
                    obstacle.push({
                        x: 512,
                        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * ref.north.height)
                    });
                }
                ref.saveObstacle(obstacle);
                console.log(obstacle[0].x); // the values are right, but they do not appear?
            }
            ref.ctx.drawImage(ref.bg, 0, 0);
            // ref.ctx.drawImage(ref.north, 250, 0); uncommenting this makes it show up
            // ref.ctx.drawImage(ref.south, 250, 0 + constant);
            ref.ctx.drawImage(ref.fg, 0, ref.c.height - ref.fg.height);
            ref.ctx.drawImage(ref.player, ref.pX, ref.pY);

            ref.pY += ref.gravity

            window.requestAnimationFrame(ref.draw.bind(this));
        }

    }

    moveUp(e) {
        if (e == "w" || e == " " || e == "ArrowUp") {
            this.pY -= 30;
            console.log(this.obstacle);
        }

    }
}
let game = new Game(canvas);
```

[How it looks like with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpMVR.png)

[How the working code should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukQ6q.png)

Comment: In your draw method, you have `let ref = this.reference;` but it's not set to anything. And your draw method is never called in the first place either.

Comment: @ChrisG I had a similar issue earlier and got my answer throught here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66816536/html5-canvas-images-are-not-loading-using-drawimage. ref is set after requestAnimationFrame, since that loops it again (at least that's how I understand it)

Draw method is called at least five times in the onload event.. Everything seems to work besides the loop drawImage() and I don't understand why >:/

Comment: Use `console.log()` to debug everything. Whether functions are called, what vars actually contain, etc. Should be simple to find the issue that way

Comment: @ChrisG I did that before, but couldn't figure it out. If I moved the imageDraw()'s inside of the loop, they wouldn't work either, but outside of it they do, which is strange, since everything else in the loop (such as console.log()) works. Is there a way to track where the two drawImage()'s inside of the loop went? Added pictures to the post

Comment: Looks like the onload draw calls not binding `this` is the problem, Try adding `this.draw = this.draw.bind(this);` to the contructor

Comment: @ChrisG Hmmm, that gives me a typeError: Cannot read property 'loadedSprites' of undefined at Game.draw

I've binded at requestAnimationFrame already though. And modifying it (replacing with 'this' or 'rel' gave me errors.

I've been trying to solve this since yesterday and this is really burying me under the ground ://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and most importantly: you're mixing two completely different things here.

```
this.player.onload = this.draw;
```

and

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(ref.draw.bind(this));
```

Both execute the same function. Technically this is possible of course but it makes things a bit confusing. I'd recommend setting up an additional function for the onload events, so you can trigger requestAnimationFrame there as soon as all images finished loading.

```
this.player = new Image(); 
this.player.reference = this;
this.player.onload = this.loaded;

  loaded() {
    let ref = this.reference;
    ref.loadedSprites += 1;
    if (ref.loadedSprites >= ref.sprites) {
      // continue
    }
  }
```

Second, the correct 'context' for the **this** keyword needs to be passed to the .bind() function. It should always be your Game class's object. So replace the `// continue` above with:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(ref.draw.bind(ref));
```

Now the `draw()` function needs some modifications. As we gave it the proper context for the this keyword, we do not longer need to use the reference - we can simply use **this** now.

Here's the complete example:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
class Game {
  constructor(c) {

    this.c = c; //canvas
    this.ctx = c.getContext("2d"); // context
    this.sprites = 5;
    this.loadedSprites = 0;
    this.score = 0;
    this.gravity = 1.5

    this.player = new Image();
    this.player.reference = this;
    this.bg = new Image();
    this.bg.reference = this;
    this.fg = new Image();
    this.fg.reference = this;
    this.north = new Image();
    this.north.reference = this;
    this.south = new Image();
    this.south.reference = this;

    //obstacle coordinates
    this.obstacle = [];
    this.obstacle[0] = {
      x: this.c.width,
      y: 0,
      // reference: this
    }
    this.obstacle.reference = this;

    this.pX = 10; // player starting location
    this.pY = 150;

    // set sprite locations and load.
    this.player.onload = this.loaded;
    this.player.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/237/20/20";

    this.bg.onload = this.loaded;
    this.bg.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/22/20/20";

    this.fg.onload = this.loaded;
    this.fg.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/30/20/20";

    this.north.onload = this.loaded;
    this.north.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/37/20/20";

    this.gap = 85;
    this.constant = this.north.height + this.gap;

    this.south.onload = this.loaded;
    this.south.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/137/20/20";


    console.log(`AAA: ${this.obstacle[0].x}`);
    console.log(`LAUNCH is: ${this.obstacle[0]}`);



    $(document).on('keydown', (e) => {
      this.moveUp(e.key)
    });
    console.log("Game constructor:", this);
  }

  loadObstacle() {
    return this.obstacle;
  }

  saveObstacle(obstacle) {
    this.obstacle = obstacle;
  }

  loaded() {
    let ref = this.reference;
    ref.loadedSprites += 1;
    if (ref.loadedSprites >= ref.sprites) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(ref.draw.bind(ref));
    }
  }

  draw() {

    let constant = this.gap + this.north.height;
    let obstacle = this.loadObstacle();
    for (var i = 0; i < obstacle.length; i++) {
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.north, obstacle[i].x, obstacle[i].y);
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.south, obstacle[i].x, obstacle[i].y + constant);

      obstacle[i].x--;

      if (obstacle[i].x == 125) {
        obstacle.push({
          x: 512,
          y: Math.floor(Math.random() * this.north.height)
        });
      }
      this.saveObstacle(obstacle);

    }
    this.ctx.drawImage(this.bg, 0, 0);

    this.ctx.drawImage(this.fg, 0, this.c.height - this.fg.height);
    this.ctx.drawImage(this.player, this.pX, this.pY);

    this.pY += this.gravity

    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw.bind(this));


  }

  moveUp(e) {
    if (e == "w" || e == " " || e == "ArrowUp") {
      this.pY -= 30;
      console.log(this.obstacle);
    }

  }
}
let game = new Game(canvas);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="512" height="512">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Seems like the obstacles are behind the background picture `bg`. Any way to move it to the back?

Comment: Just had to move the other imagedraw()'s before the loop :) You're AMAZING!

Comment: Hehe, thanks Dr1nKy - glad I could help! =)